# How to pass "Dictionary<x,Class>" as Dictionary<x,Interface>"?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

New to both C# and Stackoverflow...please feel free to indicate if this should be asked differently or elsewhere.

Given:

```
public interface IPoint {...}
public struct DeliveryPoint : IPoint {...}
```

and code that generated a dictionary with a large number of delivery points:

```
...
Dictionary<uint,DeliveryPoint> dict = new Dictionary<uint,DeliveryPoint>();
...
```

The points now need to be passed to a routine which requires the interface type:

```
public void doSomething( Dictionary<uint,IPoint> dict ) { ...}
```

Thought I'd be able to do something like:

```
doSomething( dict );
```

Only solution I've found is to create a new List and copy all of the points which seems to defeat the whole purpose of having implemented the interface in the first place.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: The issue is that IDictionary isn't covariant, it's invariant.

Comment: The easiest change would be to make it `new Dictionary<uint,IPoint>()`.

Comment: Side note: "create a new List and copy all of the points" sounds like a strange solution for passing `Dictionary<unit,IPoint>`...

Comment: @user2864740 note that it will require boxing for all values.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point. I didn't notice the concrete type was a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the method generic over the values where the type implements the interface.

```
public void DoSomething<TPoint>(IDictionary<uint, TPoint> dict) where TPoint : IPoint
{
    // do stuff
}
```