# How to cast ObservableCollection<T> where T implements ISomething to IList<ISomething>

Tags: c#

[convert List<List<object>> to IList<IList<object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005944/convert-listlistobject-to-ilistilistobject)

[Does Enumerable.Cast<T> Copy Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198876/does-enumerable-castt-copy-objects)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx

My class, Person, implements my interface, ISequenced.

I have an ObservableCollection<Person> which I need to pass to a method which takes as a parameter an object of type IList<ISequenced>
My question is how do I pass the ObservableCollection - without making a copy - such that the called function can modify it.

Note that the answer to this question: [Is there a way to convert an observable collection to regular collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167752/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-observable-collection-to-a-list)
demonstrates .ToList() which creates a new object.

```
public interface ISequenced
{
    int Sequence { get; set; }
}


public class Person : ISequenced
{
    public int Sequence {get; set;}
    //...
}

public class MyCode
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Entities {get; set;}
    public Person CurrentItem {get;set;}


    private void MoveDown()
    {
        IEnumerable<ISequenced> seq = Entities.Cast<ISequenced>(); // works but we need IList not IEnumerable
        IList<Person> p = (IList<Person>)Entities;                  //  works but we need IList ISequenced
        IList<ISequenced> pp = (IList<ISequenced>)p;                // throws

        // Need to pass a reference to Entities.... throws unable to cast here
        Sequencer.SequenceDown((IList<ISequenced>)Entities, CurrentItem as ISequenced);

    }
}

public static class Sequencer
{
    public static void SequenceDown(IList<ISequenced> items, ISequenced currentItem)
    {
        // swap the positions of two elements in the collection here
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you can't _cast_ it, they're incompatible types. You'll have to convert it.

Comment: @JeffMercado are you referring to the collection or my Person class?

Comment: The collection, as the answers in the questions you linked stated.

Comment: @JeffMercado  ObservableCollection<T> derives from Collection<T> which implements IList<T>.  What am I missing? I don't understand why they are incompatible.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` _does_ implement `IList<T>`. However, `IList<Derived>` isn't castable to `IList<Base>` because it's not a safe cast.

Comment: It's possible to this sort of thing with `IReadonlyList<T>` because that interface is covariant. `IList<T>` can't be covariant because then casts would allow you to put a `List<Derived>` into a place where code was adding `Base` items into it.

Comment: FWIW, you don't really need to be able to do the cast or conversion in your case.  It should be enough to just make `Sequencer.SequenceDown` generic. Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29442087/390278).

Comment: @JeffMercado Jeff you nailed it!!  Thank you!  Please post as answer and I will accept.